# Programmatically communicate with charles proxy server HTTP request and response

Tags: objective-c, ios, http, charles-proxy

I am trying to develop an app which monitors data plan usage of other apps. As per the link 
[iPhone/iPad data usage tracking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5274805/iphone-ipad-data-usage-tracking?rq=1) , I set up the proxy server Charles. Now I can see all the http request/responses of iPhone network traffic in charles. Now I need to write an app that can inspect the HTTP headers of these charles request/responses. How to do this programmatically in IOS(objective-C)? Please help!

Answer (score 3):

I cannot add this as a comment (need 50 rep), and I understand that's it may not be exactly what you're looking for, but is the only way I have found to access sessions programatically.

You could write an app that utilises the [Web Interface](http://www.charlesproxy.com/documentation/using-charles/web-interface/). I use it whilst running tests against my app to retrieve the session activity, then make assertions against the downloaded information retrospectively. Hope that helps.